# How can I solve JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I started writing my bot for discord, and I ran into this problem, I presented the code and error below.

My code

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import json
from discord import Activity, ActivityType
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот запустился")
    await Bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,activity=Activity(name="Наблюдает за коронавирусом",type=ActivityType.watching))

#info user
@Bot.command()
async def info(ctx,member:discord.Member):
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Информация о пользователе',color=0xff0000)
    emb.add_field(name="Когда присоединился:",value=member.joined_at,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Имя:',value=member.display_name,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Айди:',value=member.id,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name="Аккаунт был создан:",value=member.created_at.strftime("%a,%#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"),inline=False)
    emb.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    emb.set_footer(text=f"Вызвано:{ctx.message.author}",icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    emb.set_author(name=ctx.message.author,icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
  #automoderate
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def mute(ctx,member:discord.Member,time:int,reason):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,name='Muted')
    channel = Bot.get_channel(741030349177356369)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Мут",color=0x2f3136)
    emb.add_field(name='Модератор',value=ctx.message.author.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Нарушитель',value=member.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Причина',value=reason,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name="Время",value=time,inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed = emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(time*60 )
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Снятие мута",color=0x2f3136)
    emb.add_field(name='Модератор',value='<@709725675711496233>',inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Нарушитель',value=member.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Причина',value="Время мута вышло",inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=emb)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def unmute(ctx,member:discord.Member):
    channel = Bot.get_channel(741030349177356369)
    muterole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,name='Muted')
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Анмут",color=0xff0000)
    emb.add_field(name='Модератор',value=ctx.message.author.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Нарушитель',value=member.mention,inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed = emb)
    await member.remove_roles(muterole)
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def kick(ctx,member:discord.Member,reason):
    channel = Bot.get_channel(741030349177356369)
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Кик",color=0xff0000)
    emb.add_field(name='Модератор',value=ctx.message.author.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Нарушитель',value=member.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Причина',value=reason,inline=False)
    await member.kick()
    await channel.send(embed = emb)
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def ban(ctx,member:discord.Member,reason):
    channel = Bot.get_channel(741030349177356369)
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Кик",color=0xff0000)
    emb.add_field(name='Модератор',value=ctx.message.author.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Нарушитель',value=member.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Причина',value=reason,inline=False)
    await member.ban()
    await channel.send(embed = emb)
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def clear(ctx,amount=10):
    await ctx.message.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)

#Автороль
@Bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = Bot.get_channel(741030349177356369)
    role = member.guild.get_role(740677297958289410)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention} Добро пожаловать на сервер!")
@Bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = Bot.get_channel(741030349177356369)
    await channel.send(f"{member} Покинул нас!")
    
@Bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('cfg/users.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    async def update_data(users,user):
        if not user in users:
            users[user] = {}
            users[user]['exp'] = 0
            users[user]['lvl'] = 1
    async def add_exp(users,user,exp):
        users[user]['exp'] += exp
    async def add_lvl(users,user):
        exp = users[user]['exp']
        lvl = users[user]['lvl']
        if exp > lvl:
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} повысил свой уровень!')
            users[user]['exp'] = 0
            users[user]['lvl'] = lvl + 1
    await update_data(users,str(message.author.id))
    await add_exp(users,str(message.author.id),0.1)
    await add_lvl(users,str(message.author.id))
    with open('cfg/users.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)



@Bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
    if after.channel.id == 741026839627300967:
        mainCategory = discord.utils.get(member.guild.categories, id=741026747717517367)
        channel2 = await member.guild.create_voice_channel(name=f"Комната {member.display_name}",category=mainCategory)
        await member.move_to(channel2)
        await channel2.set_permissions(member,mute_members=True,move_members=True,manage_channels=True)
        def check(a,b,c):
            return len(channel2.members) == 0
        await Bot.wait_for('voice_state_update', check=check)
        await channel2.delete()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 98, in on_message
    users = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: the issue is stated clearly in the traceback. you are trying to read non-valid JSON as JSON.

Comment: Also do not share your entire project but just a minimal working example of your code.